# Python vs R - dataframe indexing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I would just like to make it clear, because I find myself often confused by how dataframes work in Python and R:

So in R it looks like the indexing works the same way as with matrices - df[1:5,2:3] for example will display second and third column with rows from the beginning up to row 5.

But Python with the pandas package looks like it just works with rows. Or more specifically, it works for columns as well, if you specify them by name, but you cannot specify rows and columns at the same time without loc/iloc?

Comment: In Python, `numpy` arrays and `pandas` dataframes have different indexing syntax.  Looks like `R` is closer to the array case.

Comment: R dataframe is array-like table, and index is different between pd.Dataframe compared with R data.frame